# when i click to delete button for yes delete it but record is not deleting using jquery

Tags: jquery, sweetalert

i am trying to delete my record when i click to **yes delete button** but record is not deleting please help me how can i resolved that thank u.

[message confirm delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wFhDR.png)

**html view**

```
               <a href="{{route('room.destroy',$value->id)}}" 
                         onclick="roomFunction()" class="btn bg-primary-light px-3 me-2 py-2 " ><i 
                    class='bx bx-trash'></i>
               </a>
```

**Jquery**

```
function roomFunction() {
event.preventDefault(); // prevent form submit
swal({
  title: "Are you sure?",
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  type: "warning",
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: "#4fa7f3",
  confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete it!",
  cancelButtonText: "No, cancel please!",
  closeOnConfirm: false,
  closeOnCancel: false
},
function(isConfirm){
  if (isConfirm) {
    return true;

  } else {
    swal("Cancelled", "", "error");
  }
});
}
```

Comment: First thing you do is preventDefault, so the `href` on the `<a>` can be ignored - it's not used.   2nd is your "yes" function just returns true and doesn't even attempt to post/send to the server.

Comment: The issue is that `swal()` is non-blocking, so you can't use it on an onclick= and expect the onclick= to continue if you click yes.  You'll need an alternative method to POST the data - either with ajax or a submit.

Answer (score 1):

`event.preventDefault()` will block the href.

Alternatively, you can use an `onclick=` to prevent the href from firing, by `return false` from the onclick, eg:

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick='return false;'>click me</a>
```

So you can combine the `onclick=` with the return value from own function, as long as that function *explicitly* returns `false` - no return is not the same, eg:

```js
function roomFunction() {
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick='return roomFunction();'>click me</a>
```

You can combine this with `confirm()`:

```js
function roomFunction() {
  return confirm("Delete?");
}
```

```html
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick='return roomFunction();'>click me</a>
```

---

*However*, unlike `confirm()`, sweet alert is non-blocking, so your function returns immediately and then the prompt is shown.

You need an alternative method to POST the data, example:

```js
function roomFunction(el) {
  swal({
    title: "Delete?",
    buttons: true,
  }).then((isConfirm) => {
    if (isConfirm) {
      // Example only, needs jquery for this
      //$.post($(el).attr("href"))
      
      // do something for demo
      alert("ready to post")
    }
  });

  return false;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/2.1.2/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<a href="http://stackoverflow.com" onclick="return roomFunction(this)">delete</a>
```

*note*: your `swal` syntax is different, so may be a different version of `swal`.